# How can I prove that if$f$ is a bijection, then the inverse is also a bijection?

Tags: real-analysis

I have no idea in doing $$\text{if $f$ is a bijection, then the inverse is also a bijection.}$$ And if it is the same way to prove$$\text{If $f$ is a bijection, then }f^{-1}(f(a))=a$$

Does anyone could help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is bijective we know that there is an $f^{-1}$ so that $f^{-1}$ maps $y$ to the unique element $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. Thus for any $x$ in the domain we have $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$. From here you should be able to show that $f^{-1}$ is surjective and injective.